# CRM 2011 - Open a Popup from a page in an IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm-2011, window.open

In CRM2011 I have an IFrame that displays a custom ASPX page (a photo gallery).  From that page when they click a photo, a new popup should appear with the photo in real size.

What do I have to do to make this work?  I tried several methods, none of them are working.  It works fine when I'm opening the page in a browser!  When I click on a photo, the real sized photo opens in a new screen.

My methods with javascript are :

1. `<a href="#1" onclick="window.open(....)">click</a>` **=> When I use that method, it opens a new window with the complete page that is shown in the IFrame.  If the iframe is "http://myPage.aspx", it will open a new window with "http://myPage.aspx" instead of the photo....**
2. `<span onclick="window.open(....)">click</span>` => **Nothing Happens**
3. `<a href="#1" onclick="window.showModalDialog(...)">click</a>` **=> Same happens like method 1**
4. I've tried many other things, but none of them had the wanted effect...

Kind Regards,

Frederic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for your reply.. But unfortunately, it doesn't work. It still opens the same page in a new browser while clicking on it in an IFrame, instead of a popup.

It even gives me a weird behavior when I click on it opened in a normal browser.  It opens an popup, but it also opens a second screen with the page itself.

So I still haven't found a way to open it correctly from an IFrame.

Kind Regards,
Frederic

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved... Somebody has activated the "Restrict cross scripting" on the iframe on the CRM. It works like a charm now, when i deactivate that option!

Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would change this code:

```
<a href="#1" onclick="window.open(....)">click</a>
```

So that it has a target and the script is identified as JS:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(....)">click</a>
```